# Is it a goal if the ball goes through the net?

Tags: rules, football

I was recently debating this with a friend, who argued that a goal does not stand if it goes through the net. I could not find an answer anywhere in the FIFA, FA or UEFA guidelines on the rules of the game.

Does a goal still stand if the ball goes through the net?

Comment: For future reference when a friend makes a claim, ask him/her if he/she can back it up somehow. :)

Comment: I always do, but due to where we were when we were debating it, neither of us could substantiate our claims :)

Comment: There was a famous incident in the EPL when the ball went through a hole in the side of the net and bounced back onto the pitch. The goal wasn't given however the rebound was scored so the officials got away with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it's a goal. And in fact, the two assistant referees are charged with checking if the net is in correct shape before the start of each period.

The net is only there to help the referee see a goal, but it is a goal even if the ball goes through it, or doesn't touch it, or if the ball rebounds off the net and returns to the playing field.

[Law 1 - The Field of Play: 10. Goals](http://theifab.com/laws/determining-the-outcome-of-a-match/chapters/goal-scored) states:

> A goal is scored when the whole of the ball passes over the goal line,
>   between the goalposts and under the crossbar, provided that no offence
>   or infringement of the Laws of the Game has been committed by the team
>   scoring the goal.

In [Law 10 - Determining the Outcome of a Match: 1. Goals Scored](http://theifab.com/laws/the-field-of-play/chapters/goals) the only reference to the net, reads:

> Nets may be attached to the goals and the ground behind the goal,
>   provided that they are properly supported and do not interfere with
>   the goalkeeper.

It says may be, so I suspect it might not be mandatory.

Comment: So, even if the net were to have a hole in it that the assistants didn't spot, and the ball were to go through it, it still stands?

Comment: If you don't play with a net, it's still a goal ;)

Comment: Have you found any official references to back this up? I'm aware what is considered the norm in practice, but he seemed to think that it is not a goal in an official match if the ball goes through the net.

Comment: @OliverG based on your 1st comment are you referring to a ball going through the side netting? this would not count as a goal.  The ball has to pass between the uprights to count as a goal.

Comment: Haha, thanks Aidan, i am aware of that. I am referring to if it penetrates the net having crossed the line between the posts.

Comment: For remarks about @AidanO comment, I will search for a goal just like what you said, in the first division of Argentinian football, around 20 years ago, that the ball his the post that was helping the net, goes through a hole in the net, and since it was a fast movement, the ref call a goal on it.

Answer (score 9):

As per Law 10 of the [FIFA Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/refereeing/laws-of-the-game/law/newsid=1290865.html):

> A goal is scored when the whole of the ball passes over the goal line, between the goalposts and under the crossbar, provided that no infringement of the Laws of the Game has been committed previously by the team scoring the goal.

There is no requirement that the ball needs to touch the net for it to be counted as a goal. In fact, a net is not a mandatory requirement in order for a game to be played, as per [Law 1](http://www.fifa.com/aboutfifa/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/refereeing/laws-of-the-game/law/newsid=1285960.html) (emphasis mine):

> Nets ***MAY*** be attached to the goals and the ground behind the goal, provided that they are properly supported and do not interfere with the goalkeeper.

Obviously though, there will be a net 99% of the time as it helps EVERYONE to see that a goal has been scored (most of the time).

It is either the referee or assistant referees job to conduct a check of the nets always before the game. By having the nets not secured properly or with holes in them, it just makes their own job much more harder. EG) A ball enters the goal through a hole in the side of the net when going out for a goal kick.

Hope this answers your question. In 11 years of refereeing, I quickly learnt to check the nets before every game after this kind of incident happened to me.